# Hyperstack deployment problem: No such file to load -- models/application_record.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperstack

I am using hyperstack version 1.0.alpha1.4

My app works fine in development, but when I try to deploy it in production mode, I get the following error:

```
       /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:33:in `require': No such file to load -- models/application_record.rb (LoadError)
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperstack places an application_record.rb file under app/hyperstack/models/
with contnets:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  regulate_scope all: true
end
```

but also requires an application_record.rb under app/models with the following contents:

```rb
# app/models/application_record.rb
# the presence of this file prevents rails migrations from recreating application_record.rb
# see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29407

require 'models/application_record.rb'
```

do these files exist?

also the main difference between production and development is that during development auto loading work but in production assets must be precompiled.
did you miss this step?

Comment: Yes, both files exist. 
Asset Precompilation happens automatically during deployment, not? Are there some files I need to add to the asset pipeline in 'config/initializers/assets.rb'?